# Is it possible to reuse a subpattern inside of a pattern in Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to write a Regex in C# but I have similar constructions that I would like not to duplicate but to reuse.

E.g.: I want to match all to sequences that have personal names having the next look:

```
George Michael Jacobson
```

and the regex would be something like this:

```
[A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+
^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and you can see that I have dublicating parts of the pattern -> `[A-Z][a-z]+`

I just want to reuse it once it is already defined.

PS: The `\k<name>` in grouping and `\n` doesn't do what I need. It matches the text `MATCHED` in the particular group. I just need to reuse the subpatter.

Comment: Can you turn case insensitive switch on? So that you can simply use `[A-Z]` instead of `[A-Z][a-z]`. I know this isn't the answer you're looking for, but that may help.

Comment: Can you give an example of the environment this would be in, e.g. failing cases. At the moment you may as well just do `input.Split(' ')`.

Comment: What you're searching for is not available in C#. It's a recursive pattern available in pcre. It would look like this `([A-Z][a-z]+)\s(?1)\s(?1)`. [See demo](http://regex101.com/r/gF3vL1/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^([A-Z][a-z]+(?:\s+|$)){3}$
```

You can try this.Instead of `3` you can use whatever you want.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/tF5fT5/33

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain the scenario a little more.
There are number of ways for repetitive matching.
Consider the pattern `[a-z][A-Z]+\s`

if you want it to occur 3 times only then you can use 3 inside curly braces following the pattern ie `([a-z][A-Z]+\s){3}` you can use asterisk if u want it 0 to infinite times `([a-z][A-Z]+\s)*`

or you can keep this part of the pattern in a string `string part="[a-z][A-Z]+\s";` and concatinate `part` anywhere as many times in the pattern.